# Docker run to Kubernetes deployment yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

I have an application, which I deployed with docker run and it worked fine. Now I am trying to run that application on Kubernetes.

I have tried to build my deployment.yaml file but not able to complete it getting validation error.

Below is my docker run command

`docker run -e LICENSE="accept" -d --name=container1 -p 10000:10000 -v /opt/app/install:/install/resources appCentre:6.0.0 appCentre_setup deploy_setup`

and deployment.yaml file I am trying to build

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: appCentre
labels:
    app: appCentre
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: appCentre
template:
    metadata:
    labels:
        app: appCentre
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: appCentre
            image: appCentre:6.0.0
            args:
            - "appCentre_setup"
            - "deploy_setup"
            ports:
            - containerPort: 10000
            volumnMounts:
                - name: volumn-app-appCentre
                mountPath: /install/resources
    volumns:
      - name: volumn-app-appCentre
        hostPath:
            path: /opt/app/install
            type: Directory
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: You've consistently misspelled "volume".  The YAML indentation looks a little odd, and I would double-check that (`name:` and `image:` should start at the same column, as should `containers:` and `volumes:`).  Including the actual error message in the question would help understand what specific validation problem you're hitting.

Comment: HI @DavidMaze 
Yes , it was misspelled and indentation was a problem .
It worked now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to generate the base yaml using:

```
kubectl run appCentre --image=appcentre:6.0.0 -l app=appCentre --expose --port=1000 --env=LICENSE="accept" --dry-run -o yaml
```

and then modify for your needs.

You should also check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/) as @mchawre point.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Want to mention this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/ Good way to convert docker commands in corresponding kubectl commands.